# Unity: Zombie Animation Pack [Free] Not working, buggy animation

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I am using the [Zombie Animation Pack [Free]](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/animations/zombie-animation-pack-free-150219) and I ran into a issues. My controller is here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ZombieController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health;
    public GameObject Explosion;

    public float playerRange = 10f;
    public Animator anim;

    public Rigidbody theRB;
    public float movementSpeed;

    public float speed;
    public float attackRange;

    public bool shouldShoot;
    public float fireRate = .5f;
    private float shotCounter;
    public GameObject bullet;
    public Transform firePoint;
    
    void Update()
    {
        anim.SetFloat("speed", movementSpeed);
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, PlayerController.instance.transform.position) < playerRange)
        {
            Vector3 playerDirection = PlayerController.instance.transform.position - transform.position;

            theRB.velocity = playerDirection.normalized * movementSpeed;

            if (shouldShoot)
            {
                shotCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
                if (shotCounter <= 0)
                {
                    Instantiate(bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
                    shotCounter = fireRate;
                }
            }
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, PlayerController.instance.transform.position) <= attackRange)
            {
                anim.SetBool("attack", true);
                PlayerController.instance.TakeDamageB(5);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            theRB.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            anim.SetFloat("speed", 0);
        }
    }
      
    public IEnumerable AttackFun()
    {
        anim.SetBool("attack", true);
        PlayerController.instance.TakeDamageB(5);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int a)
    {
        anim.SetBool("damage", true);
        health--;
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("death", true);
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Instantiate(Explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Notices:

- My map is sideways but the camera ignores this, this lets me do tilemaps and rule tiles.
- I am using the built in "ZombieDemo" animation controller.
- I am also testing this on the built in model.
- It mostly works, but the zombie, when I get close, moves, no matter where I am, to the same direction everytime. But he will attack if I get close, and does the animations.

Comment: It looks like you're using a singleton for the player. Are you sure you have one copy of the player and there isn't an old instance that the zombie could be moving toward? The rest of the code looks ok. The line `theRB.velocity = playerDirection.normalized * movementSpeed;
` looks like the best place for you to investigate the issue. Try sprinkling around some `Debug.Log()` calls just to make sure all the values are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Ok. I was thinking that there might be something wrong with the movement code, I will try to fix it.

Comment: I have ran into antoher problem: (but i am extremely close) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71374471/unity-face-object-towards-player-in-sideways-maps