# Unity: Face object towards player in sideways maps

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, my map is sideways so I can use tilemaps. But, I have this enemy, works good, BUT it looks at me sideways as if I am not sideways, so the transform.lookAt will not work with sideways maps unless I modify the input by a certain number, but I tried and cannot get it to work. Any suggestions?
Here is the lookAt code:

```
Vector3 lookAt = PlayerController.instance.transform.position;
lookAt.y = transform.position.y;
transform.LookAt(lookAt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand it correctly, but I propably had the same problem some time ago. You can make it work if you use **transform.Forward** or **Quaternion rotation**

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign a value to `Transform.right` or `Transform.up` according to your needs like e.g.

```
Vector2 direction = PlayerController.instance.transform.position - transform.position;
transform.right = direction;
```

Comment: No, it is still not working the map is sideways so he is moving sideways.

Comment: @ArdenyUser please show us a picture of what exactly you mean by sideways